# How to fix "VirtualBox Interface has active connections" error in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

Windows 10 is displaying a **VirtualBox Interface has active connections** error message when shutting down after using Docker Quickstart Terminal on Virtual Box.

I tried to fix this by typing `exit` to close the terminal.

How can I smoothly close the terminal and get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 9):

I came here because the title of this topic does not mention Docker. I had the same problem when using the application BlueStacks in Windows 10, without Docker. Windows did not shut down (or took a long time to do so) because 'VirtualBox still has active connections'. I'd like to share my solution here, using BlueStacks as just an example. I solved this by creating a task in task manager that runs a script on shutdown. The script kills the VirtualBox process, which is perfectly safe. Creating such a task is described here: https://superuser.com/questions/165142/using-task-scheduler-to-run-a-task-before-shutdown
The script for killing a process: `wmic process where "name='BstkSVC.exe'" delete`

Maybe this helps anyone who came here and is not using a container. Thanks.

Comment: You say "The script kills the VirtualBox process, which is perfectly safe.", but are you sure that it is safe to kill that process?.

Comment: No I am not sure in sense of knowing exactly what the process does and why it does not exit normally. But after a lot of waiting and hard stops of Windows, not noticing any problems with BlueStacks afterwards, I think it is safe to say the process can be killed. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Some users have reported Task Scheduler tasks on shutdown not working. An alterantive is to use a shutdown script: https://superuser.com/a/165176/174347

Answer (score 4):

Using the bellow commands should fix it:

```
docker-machine stop
exit
```

Comment: saved me. In fact `docker-machine stop default` command will stop the virtual machine that `Docker` running on it.

Comment: Did you find a way to automate the execution of this command during Windows shutdown?.

Answer (score 1):

I was also fed of this problem but finally got a solution.
Just open the Task Manager then check for the Bluestacks Virtual Interface . Right click on it and click End Task.
I'm assuming that this is the problem due to the Bluestacks installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

oh!! thanks
i found a easier method just put that text into notepad and convert it into cmd via save as and type the name of the file as ""please click on this before shutdown.cmd"" ("" are used to denote not in name